# request.get python url-path instead of query argument passing in

Tags: python, rest, api, get

I am trying to pass in parameters into my REST API get request, like this:

`parameters = {'key':value}`

`response = requests.get('some url', params= parameters)`

but the API that I am using uses a url-path instead of a query argument. I want it like:

`/api/resource/parametervalue`

and it comes out like:

`/api/resource?parameter=value`

I've searched all over the web to find if I can somehow change what response.get takes in, but I can't seem to find it. What should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `params` optional argument will prepend a `?` before the query string as defined in the source code [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L69).

You're better off modifying the URL before you call `requests.get`

```
>>> parameters = ('param', 'value')
>>> base_url = 'http://host/api/resource'
>>> query = ''.join((parameters[0], parameters[1]))
>>> url = '/'.join((base_url, query))
```

So `url` becomes:

```
>>> url
'http://host/api/resource/paramvalue'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
```

If you have different paths in the same host that you use at different times you could even break down `base_url` into `host` and `path` and then join `host`, `path` and `query`. Remember the `join` method takes just one iterable argument.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this :
you need is a url /api/resource/parametervalue

```
response = requests.get('some url'+'/'parameters)//url/api/resource/parametervalue it's a url
response = requests.get('some url',params)//url/api/resource?params it't a url with params
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well?